# Differences between Reference and Pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers, reference

> **README**:
>
> > PS: I've done my best to explain in the best simple way the argument,
> >     I've seen many of the other topics here about it, but in my opinion
> >     any of them explains the point properly
> >
> > I know this argument has been passed many, many, many, many [for
> >     i<9000 print: many] times, but this time I (think) already got the
> >     point, so what I want to do is to expose my conclusions and be
> >     corrected if I'm wrong. If you want, you may mark this question for
> >     future readers, maybe in a sort of beginners section, I'll try to be
> >     brief.

```
 Pointers and References almost do the same things, BUT, they are
 basically (physically) DIFFERENT.
```

POINTER:

Pointers ARE VARIABLES, with their OWN address, which can hold their OWN value.

Look at this snippet:

```
int nInt=99;           //address of variable nInt      000D893F
int* pPointer;         //address of variable pointer   000C751C

pPointer= &nInt;      /*
                      * address of &pPointer:   000C751C   &just returns the address of
                      *   value of  pPointer:   000D893F
                      * value pointed by *pPointer: 99
                      */
```

REFERENCE:

References ARE NOT variables, they are just ALIASES to ALREADY EXISTING variables

More clearly: when you delcare a variable (es. `int nX=5`) you allocate some memory (4bytes) somewhere in the stack, assume its address is `000C763C`.

Imagine now this variable like a box with its value inside (`5`), the box is named for your CPU `000C763C` but in your program is called `nX`.

When you do something like:

```
int &nAlias = nX
```

you are saying to your compiler: hey look at this variable (`address of nX`), its name is not only `nX` but `nAlias` too, these names ARE exactly the same memory cell, same memory address, same variable, so it means it must already be created (before creating a reference!), this means that `nAlias` has not its own address nor can contain its own value, it's just another name of the same memory cell!

So imagine now our box called `000C763C` (`nX`) by your CPU, with inside the value `5` and known by your compiler with names either `nX` or `nAlias`, exactly the same memory cell!

So I guess that it is only used by compiler pourposes. (I'm only guessing, I hope in a reply)

If I am right, I hope many people asking for it here will get a more clearer understanding about what these things really are, the rest of your knowledge would be easier...

Finally a personal opinion, I don't know why almost all the books or tutorials I've read, before explaining these arguments doesn't explain in this simple way what pointers and references are, I see people getting mad trying to understand so simple but tricky notions...

I hope I did a good deed!

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: You are correct. The C++ standard says that a reference represents an alias of another variable. Incidentally, it's uncharacteristically clear and readable when discussing references; you may want to read that bit of the standard, if for no other reason than to practice reading the standard (a skill in its own right).

Comment: There's no question here, and there's other questions that explains pointer vs references. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c

Comment: There are some small questions to know if I am absolutely correct, I updated the post with the reasons why I wanted to write about the argument, and as I said I already know that there are many topics similar to this, but any explains the point properly in my opinion!

@Sneftel I know, you're right, my purpose was to explain it to beginners in the best less losing time I could, it took much time and practice even to me, I just wanted to help who wanted a clear fast response

Comment: I think references are basically just creations made because pointers were too scary for some programmers.  Check out: http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/
and:
http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/ref.html

Comment: @Jim: Foolishness. References were added to support operator overloading with a natural syntax. Though of course their usage has grown way beyond that.

Comment: @Jim lol, thanks for your reply, even in that FQA pointers and references are in different chapters, what I wrote does not explain obvious things already written in books or tutorials, it just merge many questions into a single, simply clear one. Well, if I'd found an answer like this I could have lost much less time and concentrate into heavyer things, that's why I wanted to share my personal knowledge! I hope it will be usefull to the many beginners (like I was) out there :)


Benjamin Lindley, I think that Jim just made a joke :)